# Morse index of minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory, minimal-surfaces

I am wondering where can I find the Morse index of the most famous examples of minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, such as the cathenoid, the helicoid, etc.

Is there any general standard technique to estimate the Morse index of a minimal hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I have briefly checked the book *A Course in Minimal Surfaces*, by Colding and Minicozzi, but I couldn't find an answer to my questions.

Any help or reference will be very much appreciated!